# how to convert a number array to a single string in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

How can i convert a numeric array to a single string, where array numbers will be separated with a comma ?

(e.g. convert A=[1 2 3] to a string '1,2,3')

Moreover, is there any way to apply the same above in case that matrix A contains variables in a for loop?

(e.g.

for i=1,10
 A(i)=[1 1 i+1];
end

As variable i varies, I need to obtain a string '1,1,i+1'

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

There is a `num2str()` function

```
>> test =[123 124 125] % 3 element vector
test =

   123   124   125

>> num2str(test) % 1 element string
ans =

123  124  125
```

and also a function to write [ASCII delimited files](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)

the process can easily be reversed with the `str2num` function, as dan pointed out

Comment: how can i get back the numeric array ?

Comment: @user3270686 just use `str2num`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
for i=1:10 
    disp(['1,1,',num2str(i+1)])
end
```

Note: Try to avoid 'i' as the iteration variable.

The output:

```
1,1,2
1,1,3
1,1,4
1,1,5
1,1,6
1,1,7
1,1,8
1,1,9
1,1,10
1,1,11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i=1:10 
    s = sprintf('%d,', A);
    S{i} = s(1:end-1);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [`mat2str`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html) does just that:

```
>> A = [1 2 3];
>> mat2str(A)
ans =
[1 2 3]
```